# Check if a document is already indexed (Hibernate Search)

Tags: hibernate-search

I'm using Hibernate Search but I can't use automatic indexing, so I'm wondering if there is a way to check if a Document in my DB is already indexed, in order to index manually only the missing documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a query on the `id` field, and optionally using projections to avoid loading the entity from the database.

If you have to check many documents and then reindex many of them, it could be more efficient to use the [MassIndexer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.3/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-batchindex-massindexer) and have it simply rebuild all of your index.

```
fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();
```

The MassIndexer uses efficient batching strategies so it could be orders of magnitude quicker than N `index()` operations, if N is for example half of the size of your database.
If you don't know how many entities could be missing, I'd use the MassIndexer as it will finish in a timeframe which is easier to predict. The single `index()` method is more suited if you're needing to reindex a known, liminted amount of entities.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if a document is indexed or not in lucene index, use [luke](http://www.getopt.org/luke/)